# elsarticle and natbib problem

Tags: natbib, elsarticle

I'm trying to create my cites and references in an `elsarticle.cls`. I have already used the `authoryear` option for the document class, and I know `elsarticle.cls` pre-load the `natbib` package, so I don't use `\usepackage{natbib}` in the preamble. However, I'm not getting neither the cites nor the references. Here is a simple example of my problem:

```
\documentclass[authoryear,1p]{elsarticle}

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------
\begin{frontmatter}

   \title{The elsarticle document class an its problem with bib files}

   \author{A. J. Lee}

   \begin{abstract}
      This document asks why natbib is not generating the references list.
   \end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

%----------------------------------
\section{Introduction}
   Following \citet{Kopka2003}...

%----------------------------------
\section*{References}

\bibliography{ref}   

\end{document}
```

This is the content of my bib file (I'm using JabRef to administrate my references):

```
@book{Kopka2003,
   title     = {Guide to {\LaTeX}},
   publisher = {Pearson Education},
   year      = {2003},
   author    = {Kopka, Helmut. and Daly, W.}
}
```

When I compile my code, I get this error `Package natbib Warning: Citation Kopka2003 on page 1 undefined on input line`. And this is what I see in my pdf outcome:

[image]

Does anyone know the source of this problem? Thanks!

Comment: You miss a `\bibliographystyle` declaration. Add, for instance, `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` (or the style recommended by the journal you're submitting to), run `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`.

Comment: Did you run bibtex?

Comment: Thank you @egreg! I was missing running `bibtex`.